# Inquirer.js, change symbol at the beginning of question?

Tags: node.js, inquirerjs

By default inquirer js questions are preceded by a '?'.
Is it possible to change it to something else? I tried exploring but did not find it mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can change the prefix of your question with the [prefix](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/#question) option of your question object:

```
inquirer
  .prompt({
    type: 'input',
    prefix: '$',
    name: 'first_name',
    message: 'What\'s your first name'
  })

  // => $ What's your first name
```